# Can't access installed Nuget Package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I've got a NuGet package installed, OpenCvSharp4.Windows, but for some reason when I try to use it in my code it is not recognized. I have other C# projects that have it installed the same way and it works fine.

Does anyone know why the package isn't being recognized?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. delete obj and bin
2. rebuild
3. if problem remains, reinstall Opencvsharp4.Windows, and rebuild

Comment: Tried both of these, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to test/reproduce this issue on my side, I clicked to install OpenCvSharp4.Windows NuGet package. The installation was automatic and after the process finished installing, I saw that there are several other related NuGet packages installed as well, such as `OpenCvSharp4`, `OpenCvSharp4.runtime.win` and `OpenCvSharp4.WpfExtensions`. It seems `OpenCvSharp4.Windows` depends on these NuGet packages.

Checked the screenshot you shared, it seems only `OpenCvSharp4.Windows` NuGet package was installed. Could you please elaborate how you install this `OpenCvSharp4.Windows` NuGet package?

**Suggestion**

Please try to install other three NuGet packages which I mentioned above manually and reopen your project to see if it works this time.